# Display partial data from a JSOn file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to display only the id and the login from this JSON file called users.json:

```
     {
        "users": [
             {

              "id": 1,
              "name": "Ian",
              "login": [
                 "January 10, 2016",
                 "February 1, 2016"
                       ]
            },

            {

              "id": 2,
              "name": "Sam",
              "login": [
                 "January 16, 2016",
                 "February 1, 2014"
                     ]
               }
          ]

      }
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){
            //get the XML data and add list items
            var url = "users.json";
            $.getJSON(url,  function (data) {
                 console.log(data); 
                 console.log("Printing data.users");
                 console.log(data.users);
                 $.each(data.users, function(i,val){
                    $("<li></li>")
                    .html(val)
                    .appendTo("ul#userList");

                 });

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Reading from and JSON Document using jQuery.getJSON()</h1>
    <ul id="userList"></ul>
 </body>
```

If I execute the above code, I can only see the first entry from the JSON file.

If I modify the code to this, I don't see any output.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){
            //get the XML data and add list items
            var url = "users.json";
            $.getJSON(url,  function (data) {
                 console.log(data); 
                 console.log("Printing data.users");
                 console.log(data.users);
                  var val = [];
                $.each(data.users, function(i,val){
                    $("<li></li>")
                    .html(val.id)
                    .appendTo("ul#userList");

                 });

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Reading from and JSON Document using jQuery.getJSON()</h1>
    <ul id="userList"></ul>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Can any please help me how to get a particular set of data?

Thank you!

Comment: Your second version [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDYw8EYOdIjYDXRsK4OF?p=preview)  All I did was add `val.name` along with `val.id` but that is only an extra display enhancement

Comment: I am a bit confused. The same code when I try to run in Visual Studio, it does not show any output. When I run the same code in "Plunker" as @Charlietfl provided, it runs fine.:(

Comment: open it in your browser, does it work there? If not use browser dev tools network to inspect request being made and also to check for errors

Comment: I tried several times in chrome and internet explorer and it does not work.

Comment: dev tools should tell you why not ... assumes you open on localhost server and not from file protocol

Comment: also assumes you included jQuery.js in page and included it before your code

Comment: did you forget jQuery.js then?

Comment: I had my jquery.js. I don't know what was the problem. After many tries the browser displayed the output.

Comment: Thanks charlietfl. My output looks like this: 1 - January 10, 2016,February 1, 2016. Is it possible to have this output displayed in a nested list?Means the login times will be the list items of "id"?

Comment: need to nest another `$.each` and iterate over each `login` array inside the `users` loop

Comment: @charlietfl: I tried to nest $.each, but it does not work. Can you please help?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bTQQplzgSOSMlATEecVY?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl: Thank you so much. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl mentioned, the second version you have works.  However, if you're looking for another way of doing it you can do a `forEach` loop.  This will iterate over the user info, and insert the name.  It's using `forEach`, so IE9 and below are a no-go with this.

```js
var userData = {
  "users": [{

      "id": 1,
      "name": "Ian",
      "login": [
        "January 10, 2016",
        "February 1, 2016"
      ]
    },

    {

      "id": 2,
      "name": "Sam",
      "login": [
        "January 16, 2016",
        "February 1, 2014"
      ]
    }
  ]

};

$list = $('ul');
userData.users.forEach(function(value, key) {
  
  $list.append($('<li></li>').text(value.name));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative method.